# TailwindCSS background image not showing up (even in local env)

Tags: reactjs, path, tailwind-css

Currently using tailwindcss v3.3.5 and vite v5.0.0.

I have followed the official [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#customizing-your-theme) on how to configure background image in `tailwind.config.js` file, but am unable to get the background image to appear on my element.

My project folder structure:

```
root
|-- tailwind.config.js
|-- src
     |-- global.css
     |-- assets
          |-- images
               |-- bg-image.svg
     |-- components
          |-- folder
               |-- Component.tsx
```

My `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
theme: {
  extend: {
    backgroundImage: {
      "test-img": "url('./assets/images/bg-image.svg')",
    }
  }
}
```

And my `Component.tsx`, in which has a `<form>` element with `width`, `height` and a contrasting `background-color` set:

```html
<form classname="bg-test-img other-styles"></form>
```

Not too sure exactly where is going wrong, my only guess is that the `url()` is wrong. In the code above, the `url` used is relative to `global.css` because I've read from somewhere that it resolves the issue (but not the case for me). I have also tried the path relative to `tailwind.config.js`:

```
"test-img": "url('./src/assets/images/bg-image.svg')"
```

but to no avail as well.

Edit: I have also tried removing the single-quotes in `url()` but that does not work also. Using arbitrary values doesn't work either.

```html
<form classname="bg-[url('../../assets/images/bg-image.svg')] other-styles"></form>
```

I tried importing the `svg` to be used as the `src` for an `<img/>` element and it works, if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Muhammad Faisal's answer, I discovered that the problem lies with placing the images under the `src` folder. I shifted everything into the `public` folder, changed the url to as such in `tailwind.config.file`:

```
"test-img": "url('/images/bg-image.svg')"
```

And everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove thing quotes from url in the `config.js`

```
"test-img": url('./src/assets/images/bg-image.svg')
```

Also if you are using next.js or vite-app, you might wanna use the public folder for images

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have tried this as well, but to no avail. On a separate note, I'm not sure which is the best practice because I have read from somewhere that it is better to place images into the assets folder in src

Comment: In a next-app or vite-app, it's actually recommended to put images/icons or any business logic into public folder. If that doesn't work, no one's stopping you from giving simple custom tailwind style like bg-[url("your url")]

Comment: Alright will take that into consideration, thanks! Tried that as well, didn't help too :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to background image in the react app using tailwind css then change you tailwind.config.css file to:
extend: {

```
 backgroundImage: {
    'background-image': "url('./assets/images/bg_2.png')",
  },
},
```

and also make sure that your image is in

src/assets/images

folder and at last you should access your image using the tailwind class

bg-background-image

you can also change the name of your background image as you want.